# How to import DWG file in Forge and how to pass RFA file as an input and output a RFA file

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit

I am trying to convert my existing Revit Addin to run on Forge Design Automation. In my code I have a step where I import a DWG file. If I am passing the DWG file as an input parameter how do I reference it in my code to go and import the file? Also how do I specify my RFA file as an input instead of a RVT in the Activity Commandline?

```
“commandLine": [ "$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe /i $(args[rvtFile].path) /al $(appbundles[CountItApp].path)" ],”
```

Current Code Below

//Get Document
            _rvtDoc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document;

```
        DWGImportOptions DIO = new DWGImportOptions();
        DIO.ColorMode = ImportColorMode.Preserved;
        //DIO.Unit = ImportUnit.Foot;
        DIO.CustomScale = 1.00;
        DIO.Placement = ImportPlacement.Origin;
        ElementId eleID = new ElementId(1234);
        string path = @"C:\Logan\BIM Dev\Reference Files\NewTestVAV_Exploded.dwg";
        View nv = _rvtDoc.ActiveView;
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass the DWG file as the input file, you need to:

1. Add one more parameter in your activity like:

   ```
       "inputDwg": {
       "verb": "get",
       "description": "input Dwg file",
       "localName": "input.dwg"
       },
   ```
2. Then, pass the url of your dwg in your workitem.
3. Handle the Dwg file within your Plugin, the code should be very similar as what you have, but just remember that you can not doc.ActiveView since it's not working, you need to get it manually, and the path of your Dwg file should be ***Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+@"\input.dwg"***

   ```
   DWGImportOptions DIO = new DWGImportOptions();
   DIO.ColorMode = ImportColorMode.Preserved;
   //DIO.Unit = ImportUnit.Foot;
   DIO.CustomScale = 1.00;
   DIO.Placement = ImportPlacement.Origin;
   ElementId eleID = new ElementId(1234);
   string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+@"\input.dwg";
   View nv = //Find the view you want here
   doc.Import(path, DIO, nv, eleId );
   ```

Hope it helps;)